# Jersey/Tomcat app throws no such method execption for ReflectionHelper.resolveField after upgrade to jersey 2.21

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I have a pretty simple Jersey 2 app running in tomcat.  It is build with maven and maven produces a war file.   It worked fine when I was on Jersey 2.16.   I have "RELEASE" in my pom for dependency versions and I today I rebuilt which fetched Jersey 2.21.   Got this error after going to 2.21.  I have oracle jdk 8 and tomcat 7.0.39

```
    Aug 26, 2015 12:16:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.resolveField(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getFieldInjectees(Utilities.java:1911)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:160)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:179)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:723)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:678)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:463)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:477)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1620)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.addConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2005)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationImpl.commit(DynamicConfigurationImpl.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.bind(Injections.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:328)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
```

Here is my maven config:

```
        ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
...
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this issue too. In my case it was caused by two version of Jersey libraries - 2.19 and 2.21 - used together.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.19
org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:2.21
```

Comment: It turned out to be something like that for me, too.

Answer (score 2):

For people who search for similar exceptions in the future.

For me I had to exclude old `2.4.0-b34` version of hk2-locator from `jersey-container-servlet`:

```
compile (group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', 
         name: 'jersey-container-servlet', 
         version: '2.23.1') {
              exclude group: 'org.glassfish.hk2', module: 'hk2-locator' 
}
```

because transitively `2.4.0-b34` was included. Using `hk2-locator:2.4.0` explicitly solved it.

Potentially, for all `NoSuchMethodError` in Jersey/hk2/Jackson look to match Jersey with right dependencies by printing out the Maven/Gradle dependency tree.